# Private docker registry on Kubernetes not visible to other pods

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I have a CoreOS base Kubernetes deployment.  I followed the instruction on GitHub to set up a private Docker registry:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/registry/README.md

The registry came up and the registry proxy also came up:

```
$ kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-dns-v9-hd0hz                 4/4       Running   0          1d
kube-registry-proxy-10.1.52.113   1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-registry-proxy-10.1.52.114   1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-registry-proxy-10.1.52.117   1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-registry-proxy-10.1.52.118   1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-registry-v0-ib8vx            1/1       Running   0          1d
kubernetes-dashboard-17zfm        1/1       Running   0          1d
```

I was also able to push private image using the port-forward method (port forward to either the registry pod or the registry proxy pod.)  But when I try to use the image, I get PullImageError:

```
kubectl run -i --tty ubuntu --image=localhost:5000/myfirstubuntu/ubuntu --restart=Never -- bash
```

And if I just create a new container with plain ubuntu and try to curl localhost:5000, I don't get the 404 error as shown in the instruction so looks like the pod on the same node is not talking to the registry-proxy as expected.  What are the ways to further debug this?

Comment: I am using calico for network

Answer (score 0):

run `docker images`  to make sure that the value of your image "REPOSITORY" is "localhost:5000/myfirstubuntu/ubuntu"

```
[root@centos7 ~]# docker images    
REPOSITORY                                            TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
localhost:5000/myfirstubuntu/ubuntu                   latest               05e197984182        18 hours ago        516.7 MB
```

Comment: Yes, the image is in the repository when I did curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog

Answer (score 0):

Can try add configuration item in /etc/default/docker file
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry=localhost:5000"
then service docker restart

Hope to provide some reference!

Comment: be more descriptive..!!

Comment: According to the document, the whole point of the registry proxy is so that we don't have to do this.  But even if I added these it didn't work.  I get getsockopt: connection refused.  Instead of specifying localhost, I use the registry k8s IP instead, but then I get "tls: oversized record received with length 20527"  (I have also added the k8s IP to the insecure-registry

Comment: Looks like once I setup the insecure-registry for with the cluster IP properly, things works.  (localhost:5000 still doesn't).  For CoreOS, add this unit:
`
  - name: "docker.service"
      drop-ins:
      - name: "10-insecure-registry.conf"
        content: |
          [Service]
          Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=$docker_opts"`